# Dimension of irreducible representation associated to a Young tableau

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

This might be a classic question, but since I am new to representation theory of the symmetric group, I am asking it here.

Suppose that $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \lambda_k$ and $\rho$ be the irreducible representation of $S_n$ associated with Young tableau $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$ where $n=\sum \lambda_i$. What can be said about dimension of $\rho$? I am specifically interested in the case where we have two rows (i.e. $k=2$) and the case where $\lambda_i =1$ for $i\geq 3$.

Comment: This is not a research level question. You should use MSE for questions like that.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko we all have to start somewhere, and this strikes me as a question that a researcher in Area One may encounter that is basic/easy for a researcher in Area Two

Comment: @YemonChoi I think that a topic that is discussed in nearly every (non-advanced) course on representation theory is clearly not a research level question. Frankly, I am puzzled why the OP did not bother to open a representation theory textbook first.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Because when you're not in the field, you don't know what is easy.

Comment: Actually, it is rather bizarre that the OP knew that there exists an irreducible representation associated with a Young Tableau, and however he did not know the hook length formula. Usually, the two things go (almost) together, at least in the literature I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classical application of Frobenius formula and Vandermonde determinant. We have $$\dim V_{\lambda}=\frac{n!}{l_1! \cdots l_k!} \prod_{i<j}(l_i-l_j),$$
where $l_i=\lambda_i+k-i$. See Section 4.1 of

W. Fulton, J. Harris: *Representation Theory* (*a first course*), GTM **129** (1991).

Comment: maybe one should also mention the term  "[Hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) "...

Comment: Right. It is contained in the given reference.